# SVG animation in wordpress - fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, svg

I have got an easy animation which works on normal HTML site but not when I copy the code to wordpress post.

I have creted a child theme, copied the style, copied the js. And it does not work. I have checked before - jquery script worked. I added a plugin "Add Full SVG Support". Wordpress displays the SVG but somehow does not style it.

My HTML

```
<div class="icon-box">
<h3 class="text-box">TESTING</h3>
<a href="some link">
<img id="imgswap" class="img-btn svg" src="link to file/checkmark2.svg">
</a>
```

My CSS

```
svg {
    width: 75px; 
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    fill: #016fa0;
}

svg:hover {
    fill: #6c91a2;
}
```

My JS

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j('img.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = $j(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

        $j.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = $j(data).find('svg');

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');

    });
```

Comment: I suppose the domain from which you are running your wordpress installation is different from your html site? is `link to file/checkmark2.svg` on a different server than your wp installation?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you need to specify that it is a class as svg is not a type of html tag -

```
.svg {
    width: 75px; 
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    fill: #016fa0;
}

.svg:hover {
    fill: #6c91a2;
}
```